# How to evaluate a logical statement in a parameter of a macro

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I have the following macro definitions:

```
#define _mMRX0(xloc, yloc, code, data, supp, ref)
#define _mMRX1(xloc, yloc, code, data, supp, ref)      (xloc), (yloc), (((code) + 0x80) & 0xFF), (((code) + 0x80) >> 8), (dDUMMYMRX), (supp), 0, (ref),
#define mMRX(cond, xloc, yloc, code, data, supp, ref)  _mMRX##cond(xloc, yloc, code, data, supp, ref)
```

I want to use these on the following source:

```
const unsigned char varb00[][8] = {
  mMRX(0,25,22,12,0,0,27)
  mMRX(1,25,22,12,0,0,27)
  mMRX(1,1,29,12,0,0,21)
  mMRX(1,1,36,12,0,0,22)
  mMRX(1,25,22,1,0,0,27)
  mMRX(1,1,29,1,0,0,21)
  mMRX(1,1,36,2,0,0,22)
  mMRX(((cfgSTORAGE)^1),24,8,1,0,0,3) // <- this is not yet working
  mMRX(cfgSTORAGE,24,8,1,0,0,3)       // <- this is not yet working
};
```

`cfgSTORAGE` is defined either 0 or 1 in a config file as the 1st step of the compilation.
There are around 25 different `cfgXYZ` defines in the config file. Sometimes the `cfgXYZ` only, sometimes with the XOR stuff. All of them could be possibly used in the 1st parameter as condition.

During compilation the files where the 1st parameter is 0 are nicely omitted. But I have issues with the last line.

I would like to extend the macros on the top to be able to deal with such conditions `((cfgSTORAGE)^1)` before compilation, so if `cfgSTORAGE` is defined as 1, the last line will not be compiled.

How could I do this? (using an old Ansi-c compiler, so no fancy C++11 available)

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```c
#if cfgStorage
#  define mMRX_CfgStorage    _mMRX1
#  define mMRX_NotCfgStorage _mMRX0
#else
#  define mMRX_CfgStorage    _mMRX0
#  define mMRX_NotCfgStorage _mMRX1
#endif

const unsigned char varb00[][8] = {
  mMRX(0,25,22,12,0,0,27)
  mMRX(1,25,22,12,0,0,27)
  mMRX(1,1,29,12,0,0,21)
  mMRX(1,1,36,12,0,0,22)
  mMRX(1,25,22,1,0,0,27)
  mMRX(1,1,29,1,0,0,21)
  mMRX(1,1,36,2,0,0,22)
  mMRX_NotCfgStorage(24,8,1,0,0,3)
};
```

Comment: Well, the problem is that there are around 25 different cfgXYZ macro definitions. It was not stated in the initial post, sorry (I updated the initial post with this information). So it would be too complicated with all these separate `mMRX_NotCfgXYZ` constructions.

Comment: @user2448122 Well, in my mind, adding 25 different cfg macros isn't that big a deal.  You can cut/paste/edit the sample one here 25 times and be done with it in a few minutes.  I'm not sure there's any better way.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do can be achieved several ways, but the way you tried is not a good one

```
#define mMRX(cond, xloc, yloc, code, data, supp, ref)  _mMRX##cond(xloc, yloc, code, data, supp, ref)
```

The preprocessor will first resolve the concatenation operator resulting in `_mMRXcond` not being defined; replacing cond with it's actual value happens at a later stage (compile time), because it's and argument passed in

To get different behaviour, dependent on the value of cond, you can either write the two behaviours:

```
#if cfgStorage
   ....
#else
   ....
#endif
```

or write a multiline macro

```
#define mMRX(cond, xloc, yloc, code, data, supp, ref) {\
                       if(cond)\ 
                          _mMRX1(xloc, yloc, code, data, supp, ref);\
                       else\ 
                          _mMRX0(xloc, yloc, code, data, supp, ref);\
                       }
```

Comment: I like this idea, but I got 2 errors with this: `error: expected expression before 'if'`, and `error: expected '}' before '{' token`.

Comment: sorry, my bad; if you are going to use this in an initialization list, like you show in the question body, a multi-line macro won't work; your stuck with the first option.

Comment: Yes indeed, we cannot use it to fill up an array. The first option is also not usable, as there are more cfgXYZ defines. (This was not stated first in the initial post, sorry).

Comment: @user2448122 please give us the full picture if we are to attempt to help you here :)